# DecodeError: Error parsing message on Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am new to Tensorflow but I am using it for a NN project to predict energy readings of meter. The relevant parts of my code are shown below:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import math

from IPython import display
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import gridspec
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format
...
def construct_feature_columns(input_features):
  return set([tf.feature_column.numeric_column(my_feature)
              for my_feature in input_features])

def my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None):
    # Convert pandas data into a dict of np arrays.
    features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}                                             

    # Construct a dataset, and configure batching/repeating.
    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features,targets)) # warning: 2GB limit
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

    # Shuffle the data, if specified.
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(100000)

    # Return the next batch of data.
    features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, labels

def train_nn_regression_model(
    learning_rate,
    steps,
    batch_size,
    hidden_units,
    training_features,
    training_targets,
    validation_features,
    validation_targets):

  periods = 50
  steps_per_period = steps / periods

  # Create a DNNRegressor object.
  my_optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
  my_optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimizer, 5.0)
  dnn_regressor = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
      feature_columns=construct_feature_columns(training_features),
      hidden_units=hidden_units,
      optimizer=my_optimizer,
  )

  # Create input functions.
  training_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(training_features, 
                                          training_targets["meter_reading"], 
                                          batch_size=batch_size)
  predict_training_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(training_features, 
                                                  training_targets["meter_reading"], 
                                                  num_epochs=1, 
                                                  shuffle=False)
  predict_validation_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(validation_features, 
                                                    validation_targets["meter_reading"], 
                                                    num_epochs=1, 
                                                    shuffle=False)

  # Training the model in a loop to periodically assess
  # loss metrics.
  print("Training model...")
  print("RMSLE (on training data):")
  training_rmsle = []
  validation_rmsle = []
  for period in range (0, periods):
    # Train the model, starting from the prior state.
    dnn_regressor.train(
        input_fn=training_input_fn,
        steps=steps_per_period
    )
    # Take a break and compute predictions.
    training_predictions = dnn_regressor.predict(input_fn=predict_training_input_fn)
    training_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in training_predictions])

    validation_predictions = dnn_regressor.predict(input_fn=predict_validation_input_fn)
    validation_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in validation_predictions])

  return dnn_regressor
...

dnn_regressor = train_nn_regression_model(
    learning_rate=0.01,
    steps=1500,
    batch_size=10000,
    hidden_units=[500, 50, 10],
    training_features=Training_features,
    training_targets=Training_targets,
    validation_features=Validation_features,
    validation_targets=Validation_targets)
```

I put as much as I can so that it can be understood. After running the above, I keep getting a Decode Error as shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DecodeError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-43db7cb286bc> in <module>()
      7     training_targets=Training_targets,
      8     validation_features=Validation_features,
----> 9     validation_targets=Validation_targets)

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _as_graph_def(self, from_version, add_shapes)
   3164         data = c_api.TF_GetBuffer(buf)
   3165       graph = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
-> 3166       graph.ParseFromString(compat.as_bytes(data))
   3167       # Strip the experimental library field iff it's empty.
   3168       if not graph.library.function:

DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Thank you.
PS: I'm running it on Google Colab with a GPU accelerator.